# Is there any guide for migrating Cocos2d-x 3.8 to 3.14?

Tags: migration, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-3.x

I'm trying to migrate Cocos2d-x 3.8 to 3.14.
but when I tried to find a blog or a blog that explaining how to solve the Issues, I could not found it.

I can only found Cocos2d-x 2.X to 3.X

So, I ask for help here.
Could you give me some guide for migrating Cocos2d-x? I want solve Audio Engine Issue(Ogg File now playing well).

//I apologize for my strange speech.I am not good at English.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this myself recently. I am seeing this (posted [here](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/easy-way-to-update-a-project-to-a-new-version-of-cocos2d-x/23848/9?) on the Cocos2d-x forum) to be the best way of keeping up to date with the versions:

> Just discovered that cocos gen-libs exists in version 3.8+ for making prebuilts. Instead of the engine existing in a folder/subproject in your game, it can just sit in the root cocos folder and be added to the search path.

From this, you should be able to pre-build the game engine and then use the pre-built files in your games. This could also be good if you make any alterations to the engine yourself, you could perhaps keep a fork of the engine elsewhere, and whenever you make a change to it you can prebuilt it and then bring it into your own project.

While it may not be much help now and is probably more complicated than what you were looking for, it may be the best choice moving forward.

Comment: Thank you. My project was sadly over, but it helped me a lot to study programming.